# How to create a facebook-event for a page without posting it to the pages wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I have a facebook page, and am able to create events in the name of the page via the facebook api. But each event-creation is posted to the pages wall, which could annoy fans, when too much events are created.

In the facebook native interface there is an option to hide the created event from the wall. I s there some way to do that with the api? For doing it afterwards, I only have the event-id, not the post id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the event through Graph API, add the `no_feed_story` parameter set to true.

> You can create an event for a page by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   PAGE_ID/events with the create_event permissions and the following
>   parameters.
>
> **no_feed_story**: Suppress the creation of a feed story - the default value is false

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events